# Is it possible to use FsYacc parser developed for one language as part of parsing process for other language?

Tags: parsing, f#, fsyacc

I'm implementing parsing and expression evaluation for two languages L1 and L2. 
Important thing is that L1 can be used as separate language or as a part of L2, and L2 contains only several keywords, which are absent in L1.

I've done already *Lexing -> Parsing -> AST production -> AST processing* process for L1  and used for this F# with *FsLex*, *FsYacc* utilities.

**Is it possible to use already developed parsing process (I mean *tokens*, *AST production* defined in L1 parser) during parsing another language L2?**

*AST*: AST of the L1 will be used as part of AST for L2, and it will be used the same AST processing process.

*FsLex Lexer*: possible will be common for both languages, and I will need just include into L1 lexer also several absent keywords for L2. But **if it is possible to have separate lexers for L1 and L2, and refer to L1 from L2 lexer, it will be excellent.**

*FsYacc Parser*: I would not like 'copy-C' all L1 parsers code into the L2. 
**Is there is a way to reference in my L2, tokens and AST data production defined in L1 parser?**

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an interesting [article](http://tratt.net/laurie/tech_articles/articles/parsing_the_solved_problem_that_isnt) which mentions the difficulties of grammar composition. The short-story is that you can't do what you want to do using yacc-like parser generators. That does not mean you can't achieve code reuse using some macro-based system, but it will remain a hack.

Comment: I think the problems described in the article for yacc parsers are not related to my case: L1 can be separate language and L2 just extends L1 with some keywords, L1 and L2 have not conflicted rules and keywords meanings. I more interested how to use (better would be 'how to separate') parser (tokens and AST production) for one language into several fsy files

Comment: It's related to your problem even though your problem may not be a pathological case. There is no grammar composition mechanism designed into yacc because it could not support the general case.

Comment: Possibly you're right, and FsYaac doesn't allow usage references between parsers - thank you